# $\sum \limits^\infty_{n=1}{(-1)^n} $Convergent or divergent? Explain

Tags: real-analysis

> Is
>   $$\sum^\infty_{n=1}{(-1)^n}{}$$

Convergent or divergent? Explain

My attempt:

By the geometric series test, if $$|-1| \ge 1$$ then the series is divergent. Clearly, $$|-1| \ge 1.$$

Also by the zero test since,
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x^{n}$$ does not equal zero, it diverges.

Comment: Look at the partial sums.  $S_{2n}=0$ , $S_{2n+1}=-1$ so $S_k$ does not approach a limit.

Comment: If $\sum a_n$ converges, then $a_n \to 0.$ Is that true here?